# Variables from AHK to Java

Tags: java, native, autohotkey, transfer

Is it possible to transfer variables or integers from ahk to java? It might be possible to do using the cmd, which AHK commands can be exicuted using NativeCall, through the cmd, in java, explained here: http://youtu.be/EX0iT0NTTjw

Comment: As you might be aware, it is costly time-wise, as well as resource wise, searching for a sub image inside a larger image in java. I work too much with automation of many different applications to have such limitations. I've found the use of NativeCall, which can call AHK commands in java to be most useful for creating a logic structure for some of my applications. I now require the return of some type of variable, so that I can provide some stability and needed reliability to an application I am currently developing. Hope that clears things up.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the Ahk script from java using runtime.exec and read the stdout of Autohotkey process. Use http://l.autohotkey.net/docs/commands/FileAppend.htm for stdout.

You could also use things like OnMessage, a temporary file, the clipboard, etc.
http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/OnMessage.htm

Answer (score 0):

or you use onmessage or you append something to a file and read it in java.

i recommend using the fileappend command for beginners because it also lets you keep logs of the last thing happening where onmessage doesnt and you must watch out that you dont message something to the thing. most windows functionality is backed with messages like that so interrupting them would be a bad idea